# Help me to make my idea clean on initializer, reinitializer and disableinitializer

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

Openzeppelin has a solidity script `initializable.sol` which has some modifiers and internal functions. I wanna clear my idea on these. I am describing what i know about it, correct me if i am wrong.

**modifier initializer** : used in such function which is to be called only once. suppose i have a function named `initialize()` which uses `initializer` modifier. In this case the `initialize()` function will be called only once in one deployment of logic contract. When we upgrade our logic contract then we can call again the `initialize()` but only one time. Like this with each upgrade we will have one chance to call initialize()`.

**modifier reinitializer**: used to reinitialize a function, provided the current version is less than the version which provided in `reinitializer(here)`. `reinitializer` also can be called only once in a contract. We can do like this:

```
 contract MyToken is ERC20Upgradeable {
      function initialize() initializer public {
          // code ..
      }
  }
 
  contract MyTokenV2 is MyToken, ERC20PermitUpgradeable {
      function initializeV2() reinitializer(2) public {
          // code ..
      }
  }

 contract MyTokenV3 is MyTokenV2 {
      function initialize3() reinitializer(3) public {
         // code ..
      }
  }
 
  contract MyTokenV4 is MyTokenV3{
      function initializeV4() reinitializer(4) public {
          // code ..
      }
  }
```

But after `reinitializer(4)` can i give `reinitializer(10)`? like this:

```
contract MyTokenV4 is MyTokenV3{
      function initializeV5() reinitializer(10) public {
          // code ..
      }
  }
```

So Overall logic for `reinitializer` is if we want to upgrade our logic contract to next version then we will have to use `reinitializer`. But here comes one thing that, we can call `initialize()` with initializer in every upgrade, so its version will automatically increase. Why do we need to use `reinitializer`?

**disableInitializer()**: used to disable further initialization of a contract, also reinitializer won't work. Used to lock a contract on its first initialization. But why do we actually need this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a kinda of similar implementation with Aave V2's Versioned Initalizable scheme. (https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/protocol/libraries/aave-upgradeability/VersionedInitializable.sol)

Basically, you use a constant variable to determine the version number. Since constant variables are not stored in actual storage of the contract, and instead is added to the bytecode (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/140629/66634 for more details on that), we are only able to call the initilization function if the version number has changed, aka only if the contract has been updated with a new implementation.

This is a pretty involved concept, let me know if you have any follow up questions about this. I think this is essentially what you are trying to build though, or something close to it.